# SQL Table Joining issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a two tables: "invoice" as `I` and "Accounts Receivable" as `AR`.

`AR` table includes invoice issued (with id 0) and cash received (with id 4), while `I` table includes invoice amount column and adjustment column.

Apart from regular invoices and adjustments there are cases where adjustments were made to invoice and net affect is 0.00 on `AR` table. Plus sometimes, invoices are created and written off at invoice table before posting, so `AR` will have 0.00 amount in `AR` but `I` table has $100 in amount and -$100 in adjustment.

I am trying to create a query where it gives me invoice issued and cash received side by side and also create a new column that includes adjustment made for invoices with 0.00 balance in `AR`. Columns that might help:

```
AR.ID = unique ID
AR.ARinvnumber= Invoice number from Invoice table
Ar.Type= 0=invoice, 1 = payment received
Ar.Amount= ARamount saved from invoice 
I.Id= unique ID
Invoice number = number of invoice
Invamount= Actual invoice amount
Inv Adjustment= Adjustment applied on invoice
```

Any idea how I can achieve that? I am able to match `I` and `AR` table and cash and `AR` from `AR` table

```
Select *
From (select ar.customerId, ar.customername,ar.invnumber ar.amount, i.invamout, i.invadjustment from Ar join I on ar.arinvnumber=i.invoicenumber where ar.artype=1) inv
join
select (select ar.customerId, ar.customername, ar.invnumber ar.amount, i.invamout, i.invadjustment from Ar join I on ar.arinvnumber=i.invoicenumber where ar.artype=1) cash

on inv.invnumber=cash.invnumber and inv.customerid=cash.customerid
```

after getting this, how can I include those invoices for whom adjustment were made but there was no `AR` because adjustment equals invoice amount.

Answer:

The following answer worked for me. Basically I wanted to include all the adjustments from invoice table including those ones which are not populated in AR table because the adjustments were made to clear client’s balance related to the work done after final invoice was issues.  I used following query

```
Select *
From (select AR.ARInvnum as ARInvnum, AR.Arclientnumber as Aclient, sum(AR.Amount), I.Invoicenumber,      sum(distinct(I.IAmount)), sum(I.IAdjust)
    From AR.ARInvnum=I.Invoicenumber
    Where ar.artype=0
Group by AR.ARInvnum, I.Invoicenumber, AR.Arclientnumber)AInvoice
Left join 
    (select AR.ARInvnum as PARInvnum, AR.Arclientnumber as PClient,      sum(AR.Amount), I.Invoicenumber, sum (I.IAmount), sum(I.IAdjust)
    From AR.ARInvnum=I.Invoicenumber
    Where ar.artype=4
Group by AR.ARInvnum, I.Invoicenumber, AR.ARclientnumber)PInvoice
on
AInvoice.ARInvnum=PInvoice.PARInvnum
and 
AInvoice.Aclient=PInvoice.PClient
```

Keep in Mind the Distinct clause in the first portion of the subquery removes any duplicates as well as sum them, so it will look like one summary related to particular invoice number. first portion of the subquery is summarizing based on the invoice issues and the adjustments related to the client. and second part is matching all payments received. I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a limiting clause, also known as a where clause. MSDN documentation on [select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) lays out the syntax as follows:

```
SELECT select_list [ INTO new_table ]

[ FROM table_source ] [ WHERE search_condition ]

[ GROUP BY group_by_expression ]

[ HAVING search_condition ]

[ ORDER BY order_expression [ ASC | DESC ] ]
```

Be aware, you will not need every expression to create a valid select statement. Also you do not need to join the same query to itself. Why not simplify by running the query by itself?

```
select 
    ar.customerId, ar.customername, ar.invnumber, 
    ar.amount, i.invamout, i.invadjustment 
from Ar 
  join I on ar.arinvnumber=i.invoicenumber 
where ar.artype=1
```

But your questions asks how to limit the results to only

> those invoices for whom adjustment were made but there was no [account receivable]

Update your where clause to something like

```
where ar.artype=1 and i.adjustment is not null and i.adjustment = i.invamount
```

This will limit the results returned by the `select` statement to only those records that meet all three of the following criteria:

1. artype is equal to 1
2. adjustment is not null
3. adjustment is equal to invamount

If that result set is too narrow, tweak your where clause. I find it helpful to identify a single record that looks like other records I would like to find. Use that records unique identifier as a test for whether or not your query is working like you expect.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I tried but it did not work. So I took the result and created a new table, than I ran second query and joined the result. It worked. Thank you for your support.